# Why would SUM(COL1 + COL2) and SUM(COL1) + SUM(COL2) yield differently?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions, aggregation

This is a rather odd result. I expect these to have the same yield.

[image: Please see screenshot of the command and result]

Also below is the link to the excel extract from the database.
https://twentius.opendrive.com/files?89038281_muoyg

Edit: Columns used for SUM have NULL cells.

Comment: My immediate thought would be *rounding*. Floating point values are approximations, across many arithmetic operations those approximations can quickly add up. A different order of operations leads to a different result.

Comment: I don't think it would be rounding. The impact should have been very small and the values are summed as floating point so there should have no rounding to occur.

Comment: Sorry Jes, but floating point is exactly where rounding can quickly add up, even 0.1 cannot be exactly represented by a floating point value. A quick sum of your linked database gives another value entirely (around 2 million): clearly there is more going on.

Answer (score 5):

Probably, there are some `NULL` values. `NULL + 1` is `NULL`. And `SUM` filters out `NULL` values.

You can use `ISNULL(JAN, 0) + ISNULL(FEB, 0) + ...` to work around this issue.

Answer (score 4):

It's almost certainly `NULL` values:

```
declare @t table (Col1 int,Col2 int)
insert into @t(Col1,Col2) values
(1,3),
(5,7),
(9,NULL)

select SUM(Col1+Col2),SUM(Col1)+SUM(Col2) from @t
```

Produces:

```
----------- -----------
16          25
```

Comment: I think you're right. SUM(Col1 + Col2) ignore rows with NULL value but SUM(Col1) + SUM(Col2) just ignore cells with NULL value. +1 For demonstrating. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the null, try this (i am using the example given by Damien)

select  sum(isnull(col1,0)+isnull(col2,0)) from @t